# Tag wikis should not contain "Questions about" or "Concerning"

Tags: discussion, tags

A tag, by definition, is for questions about its stated topic. Repeating "questions about" or variants thereof ("concerning", etc) is redundant and looks bad.

[image]

Comment: Oops - I'm guilty of at least one of those. Thanks for pointing it out - it was an easy mistake for a new tag editor to make. I bet I'll remember it next time.

Comment: I created a bunch of tags where I used the term "Concerning" specifically because I saw so many existing tags that used "Questions about" and I thought "Concerning" was more concise and helpful. Now I've learned that the powers that be frown on both terms. Now I know better.